# How to see the contents of a file in batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to have a batch file look at the contents of a folder and echo out whats inside it. (Folders and files)

Comment: Is `File_1` an archive, which has two files inside it?

Comment: No it's just a normal file.

Comment: How can it have two files inside it?

Comment: i'm a idiot it's a folder.

Comment: Please [edit] your question again, and ask the question you really want an answer to here. It also helps immensely if you post at least a minimal effort to do something yourself to find a solution before posting here. SO isn't a code writing service where you post a vague description of what you want to do and someone writes the code to do it for you. We expect some effort to find a solution first from you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dir "1stFolder"
OR
dir "1stFolder" /a:d
OR 
dir "1stFolder" /s
OR
dir "1stFolder" /a:d /s
OR
dir "1stFolder" /b
OR
dir "1stFolder" /b /s
OR
dir "1stFolder" /b /a:d
OR
dir "1stFolder" /b /a:d /s
```

the /b switch prints it out without all the meta info, the /s does a recursive search, the /a:d specifies to only show dirs. if you specify /b /s it will show the full path along with the name, and it will how sub files and folders. /a takes an attribute, in this case d denoting that we want dirs. do dir /? for more info on the dir command. ;)

Comment: Please add text to explain what it is your answer means, so that there is content useful to future readers who are searching here. Posting code-only answers is discouraged. There should be text that explains what each of the options are in your different solutions.

Comment: I've undone the downvote, but you need to provide considerably more information to make this an actual answer. You could actually describe what each option does and the differences between the output clearly. (You should also remove the plea to accept it as correct. It's a waste of space you could better use to write your answer, and it's not really appropriate. If you earn an upvote, you'll get one, and the same applies to an accepted answer. Besides, the poster is unable to accept yet even if they wanted to do so.)

Comment: is this a good answer now? please don't be upset that my answers aren't great, I am only thirteen and am only good at programing and scripting (especially batch files) but I don't know how to explain things well. if it needs to be better, please explain how I can make it better and how to make my answers contribute more to the site.

Comment: It's a little better. :-) I posted an answer earlier that I deleted again after the poster failed to edit to make the question more clear. I'll undelete it for now as an example of what I think is a proper answer (not necessarily the correct or best one, but at least proper to post here). I'll probably delete it again in a few hours if the question isn't improved by the original author.

Comment: thanks, I'll attempt to add more explanation to my answers. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
type filename
```

to print the contents of the file, if that's what you need.
Otherwise, please be clearer.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't answer a question until the poster actually writes one that is clear enough to answer. :-)